# php overload _call doesn't trigger

Tags: php, call, overloading

I'm just new in PHP and using PHP 5.3.13, I'm struggle with overload in php.

I write tiny code to verify `_call` is triggered but it simply doesn't work.

Anyone have any idea?

```
        class Foo{
            function _call($methodName, $argument){
                echo "_call()";
            }
        }

        $foo = new Foo;
        $foo->runtest();
```

> Error: Fatal error: Call to undefined method Foo::runtest() in
>
> C:\wamp\www\tutorial\part2\testfunctions.php on line 77

Thanks u very much

Comment: I've realize that need 2 under score on __call. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo, it takes two underscores to [__call](http://php.net/__call).